# Blank jQuery Dialog Window with ColdFusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, dialog

I'm trying to use a jQuery UI dialog window The dialog opens with the title displayed, but it is blank.

I know that it is hitting the requested link because it throws an error that I placed in one of the pages.  However, the page just never loads.  Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#theKids td a').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .load($link.attr('HREF') + ' #content')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            title: $link.attr('title'),
            modal: true,
            width: 500

        });

    $link.click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');

        return false;
    });
});
});
</script>

    <table id="theKids">
    <tr>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput query="gradeList">
    <tr>
        <td>#homename#</td>
        <td><<a href="pagex.cfm" title="X">#contract#</a></td>
        <td><a href="pagey.cfm" title="Y">#meds#</a></td>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </table>
```

Comment: Throws the error how? Where are you actually seeing the error?

Comment: Steve, I may be reading this wrong but you're calling a div or something with the ID of `#content` but I don't see that in your code sample. Can you include the `#content` div or whatever it is in your code sample? I've mistakenly called a div by an ID rather than it's class before. Don't know if thats it... just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra < before the a href on this line:

```
<td><<a href="pagex.cfm" title="X">#contract#</a></td>
```

That *might* be it